# How to scroll ListView in a touchscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll, touchscreen

I have an application with a `ListView`. 
In desktop mode I have no problems, but when I use this application with a touchscreen there is a problem related to the `ListView` vertical scrolling.
In fact when I touch the screen over my `ListView` I select on of the items of this list, but when I move my finger up and down, instead of scroll my list the only thing that happens is the selection of the item under my finger (selection changes).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show your work here..

Comment: @SonerGönül this is not possible and in any case does not make much sense to display over 10,000 lines of code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you're using a .Net framework less than or equal to the 3.5. If you can, skip to 4 and take a look to the property `ScrollViewer.PanningMode` because it is what you're looking for.

Comment: PanningMode solved my problem, otherwise i would had to scrap the entire applicaiton.